# ElasticSearch Java API vs ElasticsearchTemplate

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

With `ElasticSearchTemplate` I can easily create index out of a simple entity class. Say I want to save the Book.java:

```
@Document(indexName = "bookshop", type = "book", shards = 2, replicas = 2, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String title;
}
```

Its enough just to make:

```
    elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Book.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Book.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);
```

**Can this be achieved with pure ES Java API without the `spring-data-elasticsearch` and operations on Strings(JSON)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Java API requires the JSON however there are ES [helpers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html#java-docs-index-generate-helpers) so the code can be as follows:

```
CreateIndexResponse createIndexRequestBuilder = client().admin().indices()
                .prepareCreate(INDEX_NAME)
                .setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                        .field("title", "My Title 1")
                        .endObject()
                )
                .setSettings(
                        Settings.settingsBuilder()
                                .put("index.number_of_shards", 2)
                                .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
                )
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```